# Android activity being killed all the time

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.forms

I have a major problem with an app I inherited from other programmers.
It has a number of complicated pages, incorporating listviews with data from local DB, google maps, images, etc.
It's more or less okay on my devices running Android 6.
However the customer is testing it on the Samsung Tab S2 running Android 5.1 and it's often crashing there when navigating between views.
I managed to narrow it down to system killing and recreating the android activity hosting the Xamarin Forms App.
The crash stack trace usually points to the inside of Xamarin Forms: things like

```
GenericAnimatorListener.n_finalize, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeoutException: md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.GenericAnimatorListener.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
ViewRootImpl.checkThread, Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
ButtonRenderer.UpdateText, android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf, android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

I think they are all caused by me reusing the App object after the android activity is recreated and Xamarin Forms objects are still trying to use the context of the killed activity.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the recreate of the activity? It does not happen on Android 6 devices or in a 512 MB RAM Android 5.1 emulator.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            //initialize xamarin forms
            Forms.Init( this, bundle );

            if (App.Instance == null) {
                LogAndroid.ForceClassInit();

                HockeyLog.LogLevel = 2;
                CrashManager.Register( this );
                MetricsManager.Register( Application );

                FormsMaps.Init( this, bundle );
                DependencyService.Register<Geolocator>();
                DependencyService.Register<MediaPicker>();
                UserDialogs.Init( () => (Activity) Forms.Context );
                new App();
            } else
                Log.Information( "Application.Instance reused" );

            LoadApplication( App.Instance );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Log.Error(ex, "OnCreate");
            Toast.MakeText( this, "Error details saved to log", ToastLength.Short ).Show();
        }
    }

 public App()
        {
            Log.Information( "App() " + SettingsViewModel.GetVersion() + " " + OSInfo.Get() );
            instance = this;

...
```

Typical application log

```
2017-03-01 12:30:05.724 -06:00 [Information] App() 1.0.72 Android 5.1.1 SM-T817V
2017-03-01 12:30:07.743 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:30:23.479 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected MapView
2017-03-01 12:30:29.630 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected AddressListView
2017-03-01 12:30:33.474 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:30:36.051 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:30:36.103 -06:00 [Information] OnDestroy
2017-03-01 12:30:36.243 -06:00 [Information] Application.Instance reused
2017-03-01 12:30:37.425 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:30:37.726 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:30:37.728 -06:00 [Information] OnDestroy
2017-03-01 12:30:37.837 -06:00 [Information] Application.Instance reused
2017-03-01 12:30:39.374 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:30:41.192 -06:00 [Information] Pushed NewViolationView
2017-03-01 12:31:06.074 -06:00 [Information] Popped NewViolationView
2017-03-01 12:31:06.488 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:12.590 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:17.598 -06:00 [Information] Pushed modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:31:23.161 -06:00 [Information] Popped modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:31:26.456 -06:00 [Information] Pushed ViolationDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:32.250 -06:00 [Information] Popped ViolationDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:35.471 -06:00 [Information] Pushed ViolationDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:37.237 -06:00 [Information] Popped ViolationDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:39.415 -06:00 [Information] Pushed ViolationDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:40.370 -06:00 [Information] Popped ViolationDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:41.953 -06:00 [Information] Pushed modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:31:45.002 -06:00 [Information] Popped modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:31:48.974 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:31:51.762 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected MapView
2017-03-01 12:32:00.435 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:05.068 -06:00 [Information] Pushed NewViolationView
2017-03-01 12:32:07.517 -06:00 [Information] Popped NewViolationView
2017-03-01 12:32:07.872 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:13.364 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:16.759 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:19.459 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:21.671 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:27.835 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:30.248 -06:00 [Information] Pushed NewViolationView
2017-03-01 12:32:32.098 -06:00 [Information] Popped NewViolationView
2017-03-01 12:32:32.429 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:36.685 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:32:39.094 -06:00 [Information] Pushed modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:32:42.466 -06:00 [Information] Popped modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:32:46.801 -06:00 [Information] Pushed modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:32:48.947 -06:00 [Information] Popped modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:32:52.663 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:32:56.292 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:33:06.259 -06:00 [Information] Pushed EscalateViolationView
2017-03-01 12:33:08.545 -06:00 [Information] Popped EscalateViolationView
2017-03-01 12:33:08.947 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:33:12.829 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:33:15.900 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:33:19.431 -06:00 [Information] Pushed UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:33:45.942 -06:00 [Information] Pushed modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:33:47.473 -06:00 [Information] Popped modal EditStatusView
2017-03-01 12:33:51.090 -06:00 [Information] Popped UnitDetailView
2017-03-01 12:33:57.566 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected AddressListView
2017-03-01 12:34:04.086 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected MapView
2017-03-01 12:34:29.057 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected AddressListView
2017-03-01 12:34:36.249 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected MapView
2017-03-01 12:34:44.407 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:34:44.412 -06:00 [Information] OnDestroy
2017-03-01 12:34:44.689 -06:00 [Information] Application.Instance reused
2017-03-01 12:34:44.936 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:34:45.116 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:34:45.118 -06:00 [Information] OnDestroy
2017-03-01 12:34:45.189 -06:00 [Information] Application.Instance reused
2017-03-01 12:34:45.370 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:35:14.793 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected AddressListView
2017-03-01 12:35:16.216 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:35:16.223 -06:00 [Information] OnDestroy
2017-03-01 12:35:16.367 -06:00 [Information] Application.Instance reused
2017-03-01 12:35:16.738 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:35:17.413 -06:00 [Information] OnPause
2017-03-01 12:35:17.415 -06:00 [Information] OnDestroy
2017-03-01 12:35:17.488 -06:00 [Information] Application.Instance reused
2017-03-01 12:35:17.891 -06:00 [Information] OnResume
2017-03-01 12:35:20.564 -06:00 [Information] Menu selected MapView
```

Comment: In the error message, it is suggested that in your `ButtonRenderer.UpdateText` has a null object be called, maybe you can check that whether the method or api available or not  is on android 5.1.

Comment: Regret it's not mine but Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, but I discovered a memory leak inside Xamarin that still was not resolved when I got kicked off.